# Fixing a symfony2.8 deprecation will affect my database

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I need to fix a deprecation;

> The value "false" for the "choices_as_values" option of the "choice"
>   form type (Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType) is
>   deprecated since version 2.8 and will not be supported anymore in 3.0.
>   Set this option to "true" and flip the contents of the "choices"
>   option instead.

I completely understand how to fix this deprecation, but by flipping the content of my choices will cause conflicts with my database.

For example;

I have a car table with a field for transmission. In that field there will always be either an `a` or a `m`

In my prject I have a function that return an array;

```
public static function enumFootType()
{
    return array(
        'a' => 'Automatic',
        'm' => 'Manual'
    );
}
```

So in my form it will display `Automatic` but in my database it is stored as an `a`. So if I am going to flip all the content like the deprecation message tell me to do, I'll have conflicts in my database. How should I fix this? Can somebody please help me?

I am still relative new to Symfony, etc. so I hope you understand what I try to explain. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it?  All you need to do is to flip the array and things should work exactly as before.  No need for the choices_as_values etc.

Comment: @Cerad I swapped one array around to test it, and this is what error is showing now; `Key "0" for array with keys "no, yes" does not exist in src/FcConnectBundle/Resources/views/Consult/show.html.twig at line 502`

Answer (score 5):

You can pass array of objects and use label getter:

```
$builder->add('attending', ChoiceType::class, array(
    /** Type $types */
    'choices' => $types,
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_label' => 'getName',
    'choice_value' => 'getName'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your form builder, add the property `'choices_as_values' => true` and switch key and value in your tab. It should work.

More infos : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization

Comment: I said I know how to fix it. I know I have to add that property, and switch the key and value. But my choices comes from a function (like explained in my question) from an entity where it is sent from the database. So if I swap them around, there will be a problem with getting the correct information from the database